# Does the Delphi 2007 for Win32 (Enterprise) help system work under Windows 7 Ultimate 32 bit?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

When we select Help / CodeGear Help from the Delphi 2007 for Win32 (Enterprise) menu, we get the error 'Access violation at address 02E85FC7 in module 'htmlhelp2100.bpl'. Read of address FB300182.'.

Then when we exit Delphi we get the Windows dialog 'CodeGear RAD Studio for Windows has stopped working'.

Selecting a keyword in the editor and pressing F1 displays a busy cursor for a couple of seconds then nothing.  No help, no error.

Is anyone out there able to use the Delphi 2007 help system when installed under Windows 7?

Editing, compiling, linking all seem to work just fine.

We have loaded the IDE both with normal privileges and 'Run as administrator'.  Same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though there is a prerequisite check for the .NET framework 2.0 SDK during installation and the check passes,  to get the Delphi 2007 for Win32 help system to work under Windows 7 Ultimate 32 bit you must download and install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK (including the documentation).

If you download and install the .NET framework 2.0 SDK after you have already installed Delphi, then execute install_and_view.cmd from the Delphi Help/Doc directory, the help system will then work.

Comment: This was a clean install of Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2008 was installed first.  Apparently the Delphi 2007 help system requires some of the documentation supplied with the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK.  It apparently does not exist after installing Windows 7 and VS 2008.